# Arranging data in php array

Tags: php

I am trying to get array in following format:

```
Array
(
    [2014] => Array
        (
            [Aug] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 49
                            [1] => Third and FInal Post.
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 47
                            [1] => Hello this is my First Post.
                        )

                )

        )

    [2013] => Array
        (
            [Sep] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 48
                            [1] => Second Post!
                        )
               )

        )

)
```

Currently i am using following.

```
$query = "select id,heading,date from post order by date desc;";
$navarray=array();
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
while(($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
 $navarray[date('Y',strtotime($row['2']))][]=array(date('M',strtotime($row['2'])), array($row[0],$row[1]));
```

Any idea where i am going wrong? I know it must a itsy bitsy step but i cant think of it now!

Comment: what format is your code resulting in?

Comment: What's is not working as excepted? What output gives your code? How does the table looks like? [ask]

Comment: cant write more code here! see this pls. http://freetexthost.com/0yaoawmm6b

Comment: @wumm i agree with you but stack was not giving me chance to write more code so i had to cut to the chase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the year and month variables is strictly not necessary, but it makes it more readable and easier to see what kind of output you will get.

```
$query = "select id,heading,date from post order by date desc;";
$navarray=array();
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
while(($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $year = date('Y',strtotime($row['2']));
    $month = date('M',strtotime($row['2']);
    $navarray[$year][$month][] = array($row[0],$row[1]));
}
```

note there are some uncertanties, as you don't supply what output you get atm it's hard to know if this will actually work.

Comment: Hey, that worked exactly as i needed! i guess i was scared of 3D array! :D Thanks for helping out. And i dont get your last statement. Is there any problem in this way?

Comment: @unkn0wn no problem, it was just unclear if this would supply the array you wanted as you didn't give the code you had atm + the output you got. if I had both the code and the output I could be sure that row[0] and row[1] contained the data you wanted in the lowest level.